# How do I solve "exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper" - "Error mapping types"?

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity, automapper, relationship

My entity

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        sexs = new HashSet<Ta>();
    }
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId UserID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ta> sexs { get; set; }
}
public partial class Ta
{
    public string male { get; set; }
    public string female { get; set; }   
}


public class TEntity
{
    public string male { get; set; }
    public string female { get; set; }
}

 public class UsersEntity 
  {

    public ObjectId UserID { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TEntity> sexs { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }

}
```

And my Services:

```
  public void Insert(UsersEntity student)
       {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TEntity, Ta>());
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UsersEntity, Users().ForMember(c => c.sexs,o => o.MapFrom(s =>s.sexs)));

            var a = Mapper.Map<UsersEntity, Users>(student);

            _unitOfwork.UsersRepo.Add(a);

        }
```

I failed in

```
var a = Mapper.Map<UsersEntity, Users>(student);
```

An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error mapping types.

I use AutoMapper 5.1.1 , Visual Studio 2015 and MongoDB

Please help me!! Thank you!

Comment: can you show an example of data provided in `student` parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call Mapper.Initialize once. Each call to Initialize, starts with a call to `Mapper.Reset()` first. Try
C#

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<TEntity, Ta>();
            cfg.CreateMap<UsersEntity, Users>().ForMember(c => c.sexs, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.sexs));
            });
```

instead of two calls.